# makefile : How to link object files

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have makefile and I need to link two objects into "main" object

They are -> **oglinet.o and libshape.o**

their path in system -> **home/pi/openvg/**

Problem :I need to write full path and objects name(home/pi/openvg/libshapes.o) is possible to "make" them as Makefile variable for example home/pi/openvg/libshape.o into $(OBJ1) in makefile rule ?

Tried to make them as variable for example Obj1=  /home/pi/openvg/oglinit.o
if I compile that the compilator freeks out.

Working Makefile

```
#NOT IDEAL MAKEFILE BUT WORKING!!!!!

INCLUDEFLAGS = -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/home/pi/openvg
LIBFLAGS = -L/opt/vc/lib -lbrcmEGL -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbcm_host -lpthread  -ljpeg

main:main.cpp 
        g++ -Wall $(INCLUDEFLAGS) -o main  main.cpp $(LIBFLAGS) home/pi/openvg/libshapes.o /home/pi/openvg/oglinit.o
```

Expectations:
what libshape.o  and oglinit.o objects and thei path in system are "stored" in some kind of variable/variables 
 and if I need I can easily make changes in makefile /

After help of Chriss Dodd (not ideal?) makefile looks like this

```
INCLUDEFLAGS = -I/opt/vc/include -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vmcs_host/linux -I/opt/vc/include/interface/vcos/pthreads -I/home/pi/openvg
LIBFLAGS = -L/opt/vc/lib -lbrcmEGL -lbrcmGLESv2 -lbcm_host -lpthread  -ljpeg

OPENVG=/home/pi/openvg

App: main.cpp $(OPENVG)/libshapes.o $(OPENVG)/oglinit.o
    g++ -Wall  -o $@  $^ $(LIBFLAGS) $(INCLUDEFLAGS)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to re-word your post? It's rather difficult to understand what you want help with my friend.

Comment: Try again found vein of logic of  text posting in my brain///

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually want to make all the object files you're linking dependencies of the target.  Then you can just use `$^`.  You also usually want all the libraries after all the object files on the linker command line.  With both of those you end up with something like:

```
OPENVG=/home/pi/openvg

main: main.o $(OPENVG)/libshape.o $(OPENVG)/objinit.o
        g++ -Wall -o $@ $^ $(LIBFLAGS)
```

Comment: Makefile is saying -> make: *** No rule to make target 'home/pi/openvg/libshape.o', needed by 'main'.  Stop.

Comment: btw you do not added $(INCLUDEFLAGS)

Comment: there was a mistake not libshape.o but libshapes.o and not objini.o but oglinit.o

Comment: You need to make sure the file you want to link exists where you think it does -- the message is telling you it does not.